# DataStax Cassandra Connector in IntelliJ giving "not a member of package com"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, cassandra, datastax

I am attempting to build a minimal, simple Spark Job Server job to access a Cassandra instance; I have the spark-jobserver "job-server-tests" code and am just attempting to add to an existing test job to confirm process / workings.

I've confirmed the spark-jobserver builds without modification
I've then added to the build.sbt the following lines

```
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
libraryDependencies += "datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.1-s_2.11"
```

I've added to the job I am modifying

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
```

At that point I just attempted to rebuild (prior to adding any specific code); however I receive errors

> "object datastax is not a member of package com"

and,

> "object cassandra is not a member of package.or.apache.spark.sql"

It all seems like there is a dependency or similar I'm missing, but I'm new to IntelliJ and I've not found a resource as to what to add to enable the usage of the Cassandra Connector in this scala program.

Comment: Where did you get that dependency declaration? It should look like this: `"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.6"`.

Comment: Make sure that this dependency has been actually resolved and downloaded by SBT. Try building from command line. Check that you can navigate to the classes in mentioned package via Navigate | Class action. That should ensure that the dependencies were resolved and downloaded and that these classes exist in project.

Comment: that dependency declaration came from the spark-cassandra-connector documentation at https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md

Comment: I did Navigate > Class ... > in the "enter filename" box I typed "com.datastax.cassandra" > there were a number that showed up with "META-INF\maven" after them; there were two different version number ones as well as some .core and similar ... it did look like they existed though (is there more I can do on that to provide additional information?)

Comment: the updated declaration had the same results "object datatstax is not a member of package com"

Comment: i've gotten this to work in a blank project (new scala intellij project; typed in the import statement and it generated the sbt and seems to work); i'm trying to add it to the spark-job-server though and in that instance it just doesn't want to work; always with the not a member error
in the empty project the build.sbt generated was ... libraryDependencies += "datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.1-s_2.11"